# What is easy english book you would recommend me to read? (for ESL)

Tags: books

It can be fiction, a novel, or something else with a plot. At least 200 pages.

It should have preferably VERY easy vocabulary because my task will be to translate a random part of this book and also to briefly retell the plot.

Although it can't be a book for a 5-year-old.

At the moment, I have stopped at Harry Potter and the Sorcerers Stone. Is it okay?